# VISA modules not found

Tags: python

On Windows 7 (64 bit OS) I have installed Python 2.7 and 3.4. I have followed the typical installation guide using `pip install pyvisa` and `python setup.py install`.

In both cases when running the program (`import visa`) the following error occurs:

> cannot find pkg_resources module with " _ini_py

- The path for python is: `C:\Python27` (and `C:\Python34`)
- The PYVISA module was downloaded inside `C:\Python27` (or `C:\Python34`)

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyvisa)

It can be much easier installing the  binaries  when trying to install packages on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) to manage your packages.

As far as I can see, pyvisa is not available for `conda install`, so you would still have to use `pip install pyvisa`, but anaconda could help to manage the dependencies, installation paths etc.

Hope this helps.